# Why does my Vue-router component fails to reload except if loaded from router-link

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue-router for route navigation in my laravel/Vue.js app. I have a Post component holding individual post of a blog, with router-link tags on excepts of post like so:

```
<router-link v-bind:to="'/post/' + post.id">
    <p class="post_body">{{ post.body | truncate(100) }} </p> 
</router-link>
```

`post.id` comes from props cascaded down from the parent component, Posts.
The router-link should redirect to another component i called single which will show the single post in details when clicked.

```
<template>
    <div class="single">
        <h1>{{ id }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    data(){
      return {
        id: this.$route.params.id
      }
    },
    created(){
       console.log(this.id);
    }
  }
</script>
```

The single post loads fine. However, when i try to reload/refresh the page, it goes blank. Why does the single component only load when i click from the post component but when i try to reload the page/component, it goes blank (the console also goes blank on refresh).

Comment: Please have a look at this https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @LinusBorg's answer, with Laravel you would define a catch all route to your `app.blade.php` view file:

```
Route::get('/{path?}', 'AppController@index')->where('path', '.*');
```

The controller's action would simply return the view:

```
// AppController.php
public function index()
{
    return view('app');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you are using history mode but haven't set up the server appropriately.

When using history mode, your web server has to redirect calls to frontend routes (like when you refresh `/page/1`) to `index.html`, so your Vue app can boot up and take over the route handling.

Link to the documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: Thanks@Linus Borg. I just created a .htaccess file at the root of my app and the placed the content as is in the link, but the page doesn't still reload.